# LINQ to SQL external mapping

Tags: linq-to-sql

I don't know how to set up external mapping file for LINQ to SQL. I've read Ivan Latunov's blog post about it and it woke up my interest in it. The problem is that I don't understand how things should go. The main question is: what is the howto if I want only to modify xml mapping file? Do I first create .dbml file and then supply MappingSource object with information about the custom xml file or there is another better way?

Comment: It should stand: "The main question is: what is the best practice if I want only to modify xml mapping file?"

Answer (score 3):

look into the [SQLMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) utility (found by opening up a Visual Studio Command Prompt and typing the command in).

I think this allows you to just create maps either from databases or from pre-existing dbml files

---

After your first comment, I believe that [this article](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/08/27/changing-table-names-in-an-orm.aspx) is probably slightly closer to what you are looking for. It shows you how to load a custom mapping file at runtime

Comment: SQLMetal is a code generator and I don need one. What about hand editing?

Answer (score 0):

- [Linq to SQL - Mapping Tables to Objects](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/08/linq-to-sql-mapping-tables-to-objects.html)
- [LINQ to SQL external mapping file](http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2008/10/25/LINQToSQLExternalMappingFile.aspx)
- [Mapping options in LINQ to SQL](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/03/18/mapping-options-in-linq-to-sql.aspx#)
- [Being Ignorant with LINQ to SQL](http://iancooper.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!844BD2811F9ABE9C!397.entry)
- [How to: Generate the Object Model as an External File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546173.aspx)
- [External Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386907.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC Tip #23 – Use POCO LINQ to SQL Entities](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2008/07/22/asp-net-tip-23-use-poco-linq-to-sql-entities.aspx)
- [Linq to SQL Xml Based Mapping](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/27/25294.aspx)
- [Using LINQ to SQL XML Mapping Files - Step by Step](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/08/18/using-linq-to-sql-xml-mapping-files-step-by-step.aspx)